# Question about handling of ArrayList with Objects

Tags: c#, object, arraylist

I want to use a dynamic number ob objects from another class as attributes in my Class "Company". For that I want to handle this with an ArrayList. Which of the following way works or is better? Or any other ideas to improve?

```
public ArrayList IndustryList = new ArrayList();


//Method return an array of Class IndustryID
IndustryID[] industry = IndustryID.get_IndustryID();

//Did both options work or which is better?
//Option1
IndustryList.Add(industry);

//Option2
foreach (IndustryID industry_obj in industry)
  {
   Industrylist.Add(industry_obj);
  }
```

Comment: What language are you using? There are languages that let you add a range to an existing list, like List.AddRange does for C#.

Comment: I'm using C# for that

Comment: Then you can use ArrayList.AddRange(). See the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.addrange?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_ArrayList_AddRange_System_Collections_ICollection_

Answer (score 0):

first return this type `List<IndustryID>` from `IndustryID.get_IndustryID();`
**then;**

```
public class Company{
    public List<IndustryID> Industries; 
    Company(List<IndustryID> industries){
        Industries = industries;
    }
}
```

**usage:**

```
 Company obj = new Company(IndustryID.get_IndustryID());
 foreach(var one in obj.Industries){
     Console.WriteLine(one.Name);
 }
```